# http_auth_request php set username

Tags: nginx, php, authentication

I am trying to set up in nginx a single authentication for all the services. I have got it working with `basic_auth` and now I am trying to get it work with `auth_request` it works almost correctly, the only problem is that I somehow have to set the username in nginx because gerrit uses that to know what user that is authenticated.

The `auth_request /action/check.php;` works by that the php script returns 202 if the user is authenticated and 401 if not and then takes you to the login page. The non working part is the header `Authorization`. Since it is empty gerrit doesn't know what user that is authenticated and there by throws an error. What I need to do is in the `check.php` also set `$http_authorization` variable that the nginx uses in the header.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;


        root /srv/proxy;

        index index.html index.php;

        server_name 192.168.1.107;

        location /gerrit/login/ {
                auth_request /action/check.php;
                error_page 401 = /;
                proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded_For         $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
                #auth_basic             "Gerrit";
                #auth_basic_user_file   /srv/.htpassword;
                proxy_set_header        Authorization           $http_authorization;
                proxy_pass_header       Authorization;
        }
        location /gerrit/ {
                auth_request /action/check.php;
                error_page 401 = /;
                proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded_For         $remote_addr;
                #proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
                #auth_basic              "Gerrit";
                proxy_set_header        Authorization           $http_authorization;
                proxy_pass_header       Authorization;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        } 

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? What does your config look like? Do you have any log entries from the times it didn't work as expected?

Comment: @JennyD Added some more info for you.